# Unity: 4K 360 video VR on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

I'm trying to make 4K 360 video player for iOS device using Video Player in Unity. I had no problem to build and install the app but frames are keep dropping and I'm getting really choppy video. I imported videos with the "Override for iPhone" and "Transcode" checked, and codec is set as VP8. Videos are in the Unity Assets folder. Quality Setting is set as "Very Low", I'm using videoPlayer.Prepare() to preload video, I tried with the video format of MP4 and OGV but still getting the choppy video....

Does anybody know what is the best setting for playing 4K 360 video on iOS?

```
    private void Start()
    {
        LoadNewScene(firstDestination);
    }

    public void LoadNewScene(jumpPointData data)
    {
        DeleteAllJumpPoint();
        ChangeVideoClip(data.destinationVideoClip);
        SetRotation(data);
        GenerateJumpPoints(data);
        StartCoroutine(DisableFaderIfVideoStartPlaying());
    }

    private void ChangeVideoClip(VideoClip destination)
    {
        this.transform.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Stop();
        this.transform.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().clip = destination;

        StartCoroutine(PlayIfLoaded());
    }

    private void SetRotation(jumpPointData data)
    {
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, data.direction, 0);
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayIfLoaded(){
        VideoPlayer mainVideoPlayer = this.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        while(!mainVideoPlayer.isPrepared){
            Debug.Log("Prepareing");
            yield return 0;
        }
        mainVideoPlayer.Play();
    }

    private IEnumerator DisableFaderIfVideoStartPlaying(){
        VideoPlayer mainVideoPlayer = this.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        while (mainVideoPlayer.frame < mainVideoPlayer.frameRate * 1){
            yield return 0;
        }
        faderSphere.GetComponent<faderControl>().faderEnabled = false;
        yield break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For video playing in Unity I would recommend looking at the following plugins:

- [Easy Movie Texture](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/easy-movie-texture-video-texture-10032): Best value for Mobile.
- [RenderHead AVPro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/avpro-video-56355): Expensive but supports loads of platforms and formats.

In you case I would recommend you go with Easy Movie Texture :)

hth.